Movie about a plane crash survivor lady who thinks she is treating the other survivors
My friend saw this movie recently and he can't remember the name of the movie.
The basic plot is about a lady who is on a plane that crashes.  She survives and is rescued with other few passengers. The remaining passengers die.
Towards the end of the movie, the lady thinks that she was helping the other survivors by giving them psychotherapy (her profession). But she discovers somehow that all along, she was being treated for the trauma caused by the crash, and the only survivors of that crash is her and another man.
At some point, she remembers some situations (interactions with the other passengers from the plane, even the pilot).
The movie is not old. probably after 2000. English speaking, color.

Passengers
"A grief counselor working with a group of plane-crash survivors finds herself at the root of a mystery when her clients begin to disappear."



